# Javascript/html/d3 Cluster and Calendar based Visualization of Time Series Data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have the following task and face some problems:
I would like to import weather data (hourly temperatures for the whole of 2018) from a csv, cluster it and then display it as a line chart using d3. About 7 clusters (daytime temperature) should be created, which should be colored differently.
The end result should be an html page, which should contain a complete calendar of 2018 in the left half and the chart on the right side.
Special feature: The days of the calendar should be colored according to the assigned cluster.

I have currently imported the csv using d3, converted the date (yyyy / mm / dd / hh) and created a 3-dimensional array with javascript in which I integrated the temperature data.

Now I'm facing the problem. I don't know how to proceed afterwards.

Maybe someone can help me ?!

Comment: What step you don't know? draw the calendar with weather information or create a chart or embed it into the HTML file?

Comment: Have you had a look at https://observablehq.com/search?query=weather ? Maybe there is an example you can build upon.

Comment: @danywalls i dont know how to cluster these data. (which cluster mechanic I should use).